# Understanding javap stack

Tags: java, jvm, stack, disassembly

I'm currently trying to make sense of the output coming from [`javap` - The Java Class File Disassembler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html), and I'm having trouble resolving an issue around the JVM's comprehension of a function's stack structure.

As far as I understand - local variables, either scoped in a for loop or any other scope in the function, is managed on the stack, and therefore, adding more such variables will increase its size.

That said, I am failing at manufacturing an example of that happening.

No matter how many nested loops (as shown in the example below) I'm adding, I get the same result from `javap`.

```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static String main(String[] args, int a, int b, int c, int d) {

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
                    for (int t = 0; t < a; t++) {                     
                        for (int v = 0; v < a; v++) {                                
                            for (int z = 0; z < a; z++) {                                
                                System.out.println(i + j + k + t + a + v + z);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

```
$ javac HelloWorld.java && javap -c -v HelloWorld.class
```

Results in:

```
...
  public static java.lang.String main(java.lang.String[], int, int, int, int);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;IIII)Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=11, args_size=5
         0: iconst_0
         1: istore        5
...
```

And although adding two extra loops over `l` and `p`:

```java
class HelloWorld {
    public static String main(String[] args, int a, int b, int c, int d) {

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < a; k++) {
                    for (int t = 0; t < a; t++) {
                        for (int v = 0; v < a; v++) {
                            for (int z = 0; z < a; z++) {  
                                for (int l = 0; l < a; l++) {
                                    for (int p = 0; p < a; p++) {
                                        System.out.println(i + j + k + t + a + v + z);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Gives the same `stack=3`:

```
...
  public static java.lang.String main(java.lang.String[], int, int, int, int);
    descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;IIII)Ljava/lang/String;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
    Code:
      stack=3, locals=13, args_size=5
         0: iconst_0
         1: istore        5
...
```

What am I missing? thanks in advance!

Comment: See the `locals`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic yeah, but does that count toward the stack? why isn't the stack size increasing?

Comment: Locals aren't stored on the stack. They, like parameters, are in 'slots.' They only go on the stack when they are being operated upon.

Comment: @DavidConrad you may be referring to the Operand stack. The Java stack includes local variables, arguments, return value,the operand stack, and other information.

Comment: @RealSkeptic OP is referring to the operand stack when referencing the stack=n output from javap and "a function's stack structure." The call stack is different, of course.

Comment: @DavidConrad isn't the operand stack part of the call stack? as in stored on a frame in the call stack? alongside with parameter and return values..

Comment: The operand stack is stored in the frame, but the size of the operand stack is only the maximum depth it needs to be to support whatever computation is done in the function. There could be a hundred variables being juggled around but if only three or four of them are needed on the operand stack at any one time, that's what size it would be. See [the Java VM Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2).

Comment: A *stack frame* consists of space reserved for the local variables, plus the operand stack (plus some other stuff). The *JVM stack* consists of stack frames, one per method of the current invocation chain.

Comment: For fun, try changing the ints to longs.

Comment: @Holger so you think the number described in `stack` is not about the *stack frame*?

Comment: There are at least 3 different notions of a stack in Java: 1. [Java Virtual Machine stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.2), which stores local variables and keeps track of method invocations. 2. [Operand Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2), which holds operands for bytecode instructions. 3. [Native Stack](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.5.6), the classical “C” stack required for native method execution.

Comment: All these are abstractions that don't need to be related at all. `stack` value in class file disassembly denotes the maximum size of the operand stack. This value does not include local variables.

Comment: @apangin so you're saying `stack` **should** be increasing in size? can you explain how come it remains constant regardless of the changes I'm making?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said the size of the operand stack *does not* include local variables. That is, the number of local variables *does not* affect the maximum size of the operand stack.

Comment: @Nitzankin the numbers printed by `javap` refer to the *operand stack* and the number of local variables. A stack frame contains both.

Comment: @Holger _A stack frame contains both._, as in - memory would be allocated for both on each invocation / call?

Comment: @Nitzankin Exactly.